# Sublime Text 3 Windows Python NO Chart generated

Tags: python, sublimetext, anaconda

I am using Sublime Text 3 Windows to run Python (Anaconda) to generate a chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
heads = [range(1000)]
plt.hist(heads, bins=10)
```

But after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, nothing happened without any error message.

But I can not find the chart anywhere. Where should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
plt.show()
```

to the end of the code, and run that instead.